# Updating image Error "Must declare the scalar variable "@SmstockId"

Tags: c#, sql-server

It should update the image but i keep getting this error

```
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update SMStocksTb Set SmStockImage=@SmStockImage where SmStockId=@SmStockId",sqlCon);



        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pbxUpdateImg.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmStockImage", pic);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlCon.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query takes 2 parameters but you only have specified 1.

Add

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmStockId", <some id>);
```

to your code before...

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```